# How secure is Websocketd?

Tags: websocket

Is it secure enough for extremely sensitive information like used in banks?

What kind of attack vectors and vulnerabilities does it have?

Is the technology used making the contraption safe enough?

In all cases the wss:// protocol would be used.

P.S I am referring to websocketd.com and its corresponding GitHub page and not to WebSocket in general, since Websocketd appears to be based on inetd.

Comment: Dear Editor, I meant to ask about **Websocketd** and _not_ WebSocket in general. There are already tons of questions about the security of WebSocket.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. That being said next time a link may help - websocketd is by no means a household name, so it looked very much like a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secure WebSockets (`wss://`) properly protect the data during transfer, same as HTTPS does. But outside of this the application logic might introduce enough problems to impact the security of the data, similar to just using HTTPS instead of HTTP does not magically make the application safe against things like XSS, CSRF, SQL injection... . On top of this WebSockets don't rely on the Same Origin Policy (SOP) and thus attacks like [Cross-Site WebSocket Hijacking](https://www.christian-schneider.net/CrossSiteWebSocketHijacking.html) are possible unless the server side properly checks the Origin of the connection.

> Is it secure enough for extremely sensitive information like used in banks?

If properly used it is safe for sensitive data. I have no idea what you exactly mean with **extremely** sensitive but if these data are really extremely sensitive I would not rely on a single layer of protection in the first place.

Comment: Can you enchance your answer to answer the question for Websocketd? The question refers specifically to Websocketd.

Comment: I meant to say enhance, not enchance.

Comment: @SirMuffington: according to the website it properly checks the origin. As for the rest - it just provides a transport for data. The main security problems usually lie in the application logic which is not part of websocketd.

Comment: So in short the Websocketd is secure enough since it checks the origin and just the application itself determines the rest of the security?

Comment: @SirMuffington: The websocketd does not seem to add additional insecurity by itself. Of course it can be used in the wrong way, for example with an insecure or compromised certificate. And it still might contain bugs - don't expect somebody doing here a free pentesting or deep code analysis for you. If the data are extremely sensitive like you said you should not fully trust a single layer of protection.

Comment: Can you fake the origin though?

Comment: @SirMuffington:  *"Can you fake the origin though?"* - no, the browser does not let some site fake the Origin and outside the browser is CSWSH irrelevant.

Comment: Why is it irrelevant outside the browser? So it's secure even against packet manipulation? :O Because with Websocketd you can restrict the WS a certain origin and I'm implying maybe someone can fake that origin.

Comment: @SirMuffington: CSRF and CSWSH are only relevant inside the browser since only the browser will execute the code from the attackers site and will visit the victims site (cross-origin) with full credentials (cookies, auth - unknown to the attacker) based on the attackers code. And only the browser can be used by the attacker as a trampoline to attack sites which can not be reached directly by the attacker (i.e. internal sites).